# how to sent data / push data from a mobile app to a mongodb

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services

I am new to mobile back end development . I am trying to figure  out - how to sent data / push data from a  mobile app (andriod apps )   to a  mongodb. Kindly suggest . I  have hosted mongodb in  AWS

Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until recently, mongo was not supported on the Android platform, and there was no good way to link a mongo database to an Android application. However, it seems that support for Android has been added in the recent versions of the MongoDB driver. A thread discussing the issue, as well providing a working code sample, may be found here:
[How connect Mongo DB with Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433091/how-connect-mongo-db-with-android-application)

Comment: I read that node.js is the way to create rest api for connecting mongo db - Is this is better idea  to go with  mongodb or  parse.com will be better choice for a  beginner like  me

Comment: From what I can tell, Android support for node.js seems spotty at best. The answer to your question will depend on what exactly you wish to accomplish. I would suggest that you clearly define what objective(s) you are trying to achieve and then start doing some research regarding possible solutions. When you actually begin writing code and start running into issues then post a specific question on this forum and I'm sure others will be more than willing to help.